# MVC3 Populate dropdownlist with value and name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, html-select

Working with MVC3. I already have a **DropDownList** which is **populated from database table**.

Currently is populated only with Units.Name, but i want to populate it also with its Unit.Id (which will be hidden on dropdownlist) in order to get the ID when the user selects an item and use it when they clic on Create button (POST Method).

What do I need to modify to make it work in this way?

I'm aware of this is trivial, but i'm a newbie with MVC. I tried lot of possibilities with no success.

Controller...

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

private BridgeEntities db = new BridgeEntities();


    var query = (from units in db.Units
                 select units).ToList().OrderBy(q => q.Name);

    List<string> listOfUnits = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        listOfUnits.Add(item.Name);
    }
    ViewBag.ListOfUnits = listOfUnits;


    return View();
}
```

In Create View...

```
@Html.DropDownList("Unit",new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfUnits))
```

My Create button...

```
<button type="submit" class = "btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Create
</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ViewBag.ListOfUnits = new SelectList(db.Units.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList(), 
                                         "Id", 
                                         "Name");
```

**Update:**

Off the top of my head:

```
// Select Ids to exclude from list
IQueryable<int> exclude = db.DeprecatedUnits.Select(p => p.UnitID);

// Select units for selectlist, ignore the ids which are in exclude list
var units = db.Units.Where(q => !exclude.Contains(q.Id)).OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();

// Create the selectlist
ViewBag.ListOfUnits = new SelectList(units,"Id","Name");
```

Comment: What would be the syntax for excluding those Units that are not included on another table (for example DeprecatedUnits) and referenced by a foreign key?. For example: I want to show all Unit.Name from table Units which its UnitID is not in DeprecatedUnits

Comment: A better way would be to use a model with a List of Units.  ViewBag is alright to use but isn't recommended.

Comment: Thanks @sormii . Finally i was able to get it working with your code but with a little modification. I used    var exclude = db.DeprecatedUnits.Select(p => p.UnitID);  instead   IQueryable<int> exclñude

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewBag.ListOfUnits = (from units in db.Units select units)
                      .ToList().OrderBy(q => q.Name)
                      .Select(s => new SelectListItem 
                      { 
                          Text = s.Name, 
                          Value = s.Id// or s.ID , what property does your model have...
                      };
```